# Problem with the correct calculate of the bisector of the angle

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates

I have a problem with the correct calculate of the bisector of the angle. I use WGS84 projection. I have a bisector's  bearing (azimuth), coordinates of start point and line length as input. Some bisectors are determined correctly, but I have a problem with this case:

input:

start_point=[19.299301570524328, 50.35459214539403]

bearing=125.3385008544858

length=40m

I tried to use this library

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(start_point[1], start_point[0], bearing, length)
```

and my code

```
bearing=math.radians(bearing)
lat1=math.radians(start_point[1])
lon1=math.radians(start_point[0])
lat2=math.asin(math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(length/6378.1)+math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(length/6378.1)*math.cos(bearing))
lon2=lon1+math.atan2(math.sin(bearing)*math.sin(length/6378.1)*math.cos(lat1),math.cos(length/6378.1)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))
lat2=math.degrees(lat2)
lon2=math.degrees(lon2)
```

results are the same and both are incorrect
below is an example
[image]